# Parsefloat on UTF-8 string returns NaN

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I'm working on an app where I'm scraping data from a website using Simple HTML DOM Parser ( http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ )

On one of the sites I'm scraping, I have to convert some data to UTF-8, since the website is using iso-8859-1 encoding. Which I do like this:

```
'price' => mb_convert_encoding($element->childNodes(5)->plaintext, "UTF-8"),
```

I've converted the data to JSON to collect it in my JS file. Here, I want to convert the "price" data to an integer, using parseFloat:

```
parseFloat(value.price);
```

When I do this on the value that I've converted to UTF-8 in my Php, I get a "NaN". Is there a way to work around this?

Edit:

I've uploaded the thingie here: http://leondew.it/temp . Type a cardname i.e. "Mutavault", wait for the search to finish and watch the console.

This:

```
var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($element->childNodes(5)->plaintext, "UTF-8"));
```

Results in: string(13) "20,00 "

And this:

```
var_dump($element->childNodes(5)->innertext);
```

Results in: �20,00&nbsp , and this weird � character messes up my JSON.

Comment: Log results:

value.price = 20.00 (and it's a string, because it's 'black' in my console, and not 'blue'), 
parseFloat(value.price) = NaN, 
parseInt(value.price) = NaN

Comment: Hey @Leon! It's the `var_dump(mb_convert_encoding($element->childNodes(5)->plaintext, "UTF-8"));` I'd like to see. Including the string length.

Comment: It's this: string(13) "20,00&nbsp;"    - I remove the "&nbsp;" with javascript afterwards, and replace the "," with a "." (before the parseFloat)

Comment: Also, I've uploaded the thingie here: http://leondew.it/temp/ . Type a cardname i.e. "Mutavault", wait for the search to finish and watch the console.

Comment: @Leon please include relevant information for the solution of your problem in the question - edit it to include your log results. Such information is more useful in the question than in the comments.

Comment: @Leon (Yay Magic!) I admit, it's weird. Btw, removing the `&nbsp;` is obsolete. The problem comes from before the first numeric character. According to the source website, there was a Euro sign in front of the price, what happened to it? Maybe it's not displayed but is still present. And according to the string length, it's my best guess.

Comment: @Skwal: I guess it's because I'm using 'plaintext'. If I use 'innertext' and I do: var_dump($element->childNodes(5)->innertext); I get: �18,00&nbsp , and this messes up my JSON.

Comment: @Renan: Good point, I'll do that.

Comment: FYI [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) won't read past the decimal point. I think you want to use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Comment: @thgaskell: I did use parseFloat, accidentally placed parseInt in the topic title. Edited it, thanks.

Comment: Some of your prices have the currency in them.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of to solve your problem, is to get rid of all non-numerical characters (or dot) using `.replace()`.

So it would be:

```
parseFloat(value.price.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
```

Makes sure you replace the comma with a dot before doing that.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Euro sign.  Whoops!

http://www.ascii-code.com/

Add this to your code to help out your debugging.

```
var parsed = parseFloat(cardValue.price);

if (isNaN(parsed)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cardValue.price.length; i++) {
        console.log(cardValue.price.charCodeAt(i));
    }
}
```

You should remove any junk that you're not expecting with some simple RegEx before trying to  parse it.

```
cardValue.price.replace(/[^,.0-9]/g, '')
```

Comment: I had to choose between you and Skwal as you were both correct. I couldn't accept both :(